# Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback$StubApi21

Tags: android, material-design

Received this error after updating android to preview p and adding material design library. refactored to suggested androidx namespaces.

here is my app.gradle file

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' 
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
}
```

}

```
android {
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false;
    abortOnError false
}

compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "datazeo.android.dzreader"
    minSdkVersion 21

    targetSdkVersion 27

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()

maven {
    url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.9'
implementation 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1') {
    transitive = true;

}
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 13):

Specifically, I solved the problem by following on what's been described in [this post](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn). Although the post didn't tell us how to solve that problem, it actually is necessary for everything to work fine when using the new [**AndroidX** library](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html).

Just add the two lines below to **[gradle.properties](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#properties-files)** file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

As for my case, simply updating the IDE to Android Studio Canary or even Android Studio Beta 1 doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to android canary preview solved this issue for me.

Comment: Did you do anything after you updated ? Only getting this issue now after updating.

Comment: No it began working for me right after the update, feel free to post your gradle files if you are still having trouble with this, might be able to help.